# Month and name permalink not working but id is working fine

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

My Wordpress permalink structure is not working as advertised. When I have it set to post id or the default setting it works fine, when I change it to Month and Name, like I always use it breaks the top level menu items.

Any idea whats going on, everything looks fine with my .htaccess file

Comment: Sounds like a relative paths problem. I don't know much about WP but there must be a place in the admin panel to enable absolute paths

Comment: Linux or window hosting?

Comment: Linux / Apache / PHP 5.3

Answer (score 0):

It is file permission issue. In any reason, wp can't read the .htaccess rules. You should change the file permission of root or .htaccess file to 755 or 777. Similar issue was happened to me.

Comment: I set it to to both 755 and 777 with no luck